# How to use multiple controllers in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I need to use 2 controllers in CodeIgniter 3. I have Welcome and Paypal controllers. In routing, previously I had following code:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Then to add Paypal, I tried following codes, which were not helpful:

```
//$route['(:any)'] = 'paypal/index';
//$route['Paypal'] = 'paypal/index';
//$route['Welcome/Paypal/(:any)'] = 'welcome/index';
```

I tried them separately and also together but still I get this result:

```
404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found.
```

What I need to write, for using my Paypal controller as well?

Comment: You can have as many controllers as you need and more often than not you'll not need to define any routes at all. The only thing you cannot do easily is passing data from one controller to another (but redirection and flashdata will help get around that). Just make sure all your controllers adhere to CI's naming convention (both for filenames and class names) and you'll be ok

Comment: The question is confusing. Can you not just used 1 controller and separate them by method? 
welcome/index and welcome/paypal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, for example, you want to go to the URL `https://example.com/paypal` you do not need a route if the Paypal controller has an `index` function.

If you wanted a way to "buy" a pair of socks that used the URL `https://example.com/buy/socks` but wanted to handle this request using the PayPal controller method `buy($item)`, then you need a `$route`.

```
$route['buy/(:any)'] = 'paypal/buy/$1';
```

But you do not need a route if your "buy" URL is `https://example.com/paypal/buy/socks`

The only time you need to define a `$route` is when you want to deviate from CodeIgniter's `controller/function[/arg1[/arg2[...]]` URI pattern.

Your problems may not be route related. Be certain you followed the CodeIgniter rules for controller file and class naming? The name of the file must begin with an uppercase letter, i.e. `Paypal.php` and the class definition must match the file name exactly. i.e.

```
class Paypal extends CI_Controller {
```

Comment: For going to URL you told there is no need for routing, but it gives me same error, 404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found.
my Paypal.php is in controller folder and it is written exactly how you showed

Comment: Have you followed the naming rules?

Answer (score 0):

What i got from your question is that you want the `paypal` controller to be rerouted or redirected to `welcome` controller.

if i got it right, you can simply do that with `redirect` .. in your `paypal` controller use `redirect` in your `construct` or `index` to redirect you to `welcome` controller

Comment: Actually no, I need to call and use Paypal controller when I need to make a payment, so in shop, I will put a button called buy and just use Paypal controller this time. In all other cases I just use Welcome controller

Comment: So you basically need it to be accessed only via your button and not url, right? .. if that so you can make a check in your paypal's controller constructor to redirect in case of url request and continue execution if it is a post request .. if i got it wrong again please clarify in more details.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot call Paypal controller it always say The page you requested was not found. I need a way to write route to call Paypal controller

Comment: Maybe you need to follow the file and class naming rules.